# Find elements on page by HREF attribute of by multiple classes

Tags: python, selenium

i am using Selenium library and python.
On page i got multiple offers, every has same beginning of the link https://www.example.com/offer/....
And same classes, but the problem is i couldn't find element which has more than one class. It also has the same attribute "data-cy"

I tried

```
offerName = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'marginright5') and contains(@class, 'link') and contains(@class, 'linkWithHash') and contains('detailsLink')]")
```

But it didn't worked because of this error

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: Given xpath expression "//a[contains(@class, 'marginright5') and contains(@class, 'link') and contains(@class, 'linkWithHash') and contains('detailsLink')]" is invalid: [Exception... "<no message>"  nsresult: "0x8060000d (<unknown>)"  location: "JS frame :: chrome://marionette/content/element.js :: element.findByXPath :: line 387"  data: no]
```

How i can find them?

Comment: Can you share the URL you're trying to scrape?

Comment: thats https://www.olx.pl/pomorskie/q-macbook/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well Like the error message says your xpath is invalid, 
I can see one error in the last 'contains'.

Try change this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'marginright5') and contains(@class, 'link') and contains(@class, 'linkWithHash') and contains('detailsLink')]"
```

To this:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//a[contains(@class, 'marginright5') and contains(@class, 'link') and contains(@class, 'linkWithHash') and contains(@class, 'detailsLink')]"
```

Comment: thanks <3, it works, do u have any idea how should i now scan for all elements on page and save them to array?

Comment: What do you mean "all elements"?? All links in this format? Use find_elements_by_xpath